# How do I set the key of {t('key', {value})} dynamically with react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I am writing the top navbar with React and I am trying to implement the translation with react-i18next.
Everything works until U try to set the key of `{t('HOW DO I GET THIS DYNAMIC??'}` dynamically.

I loop through the array of the items of the navbar and for each one of them I get the dynamic value and set it as the value of the variable inside the translation.json, but I cannot make the key dynamic, I tried with {item} but  is not working.

Code:

```
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const menuItem = ['Pool', 'Mining', 'Leveraged', 'Lock up', 'Docs', 'Profile'];
  {menuItem.map((item, idx) => (
    <Link key={item} to="/">
      <Button className={classes.item}>{t('HOW DO I GET THIS DYNAMIC??')}</Button>
    </Link>
  ))}
```

This is the en translation file:

```
{
    "Pool": "Pool",
    "Mining": "Mining",
    "Leveraged": "Leveraged",
    "Lock up": "Lock Up",
    "Docs": "Docs",
    "Profile": "Profile"
}
```

Ant this is my zh translation file:

```
{
    "Pool": "存款池",
    "Mining": "存款挖矿",
    "Leveraged": "杠杆挖矿",
    "Lock up": "锁仓",
    "Docs": "文档",
    "Profile": "我的"
}
```

Comment: What is this method 't' and what have you named your object of translations? Is your object of translations 't'? In which case call it like this: t[item] using square brackets to get the object property.

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to mention that. I just added it. It is from the main doc. Anyway, your solution works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `t` function you can call that value dynamically with `${item}` or `[item]` as `{item}` will not work. Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

According to the i18next documentation: you can access the translation like this:

```js
t([item])
```

https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/essentials#multiple-fallback-keys

Comment: ths yield the same results for me. I am getting translation key back